# Calculate ways to represent 6-bit binary without any two contiguous 1s

Tags: probability

> How many binary numbers can be represented using a 6-bit number that
>   does not have two contiguous 1s? For example : "101010" does not have
>   two contiguous 1s.

I would love to know which method I can apply to solve this question. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider having the number: 000.

We have 4 slots to insert the 1s, before, between and after the sequence of 0s. This will allow for no 1s to be contiguous.

We pick 3 of these to insert the 1s. $\binom{4}{3}=4$.

Similarly, consider the number: 0000.

We have 5 slots to insert 2 1's and this can be done in $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways.

Consider the number: 00000

We have 6 slots to insert the number 1, and you can form $\binom{6}{1}=6$ distinct numbers from this.

And of course, we have 000000.

Adding: $4+6+10+1=21$ numbers, as required.

Comment: Thanks! But your answer is wrong, the answer is 21

Comment: I had the answer, but they don't give me any explanation, so I have to ask here!

Comment: @f855a864 Don't worry, I erroneously assumed that there had to be 3 1s and 3 0s - my apologies. I'll fix it up now.

Comment: @f855a864 Is this answer to your satisfaction?

Comment: Yes the anwser is correct, but I still can wrap my head around the solution. Can you please elaborate a little more? When you said `We have 4 slots to insert the 0s into the number 111`, I don't really get it here!

Comment: @f855a864 Of course. If you look at 111 like this: $_0_0_0_$, perhaps it will become clearer. _ represent the spaces where you can insert the 1s to make a 6 digit binary number. Essentially, what I am doing is inserting 1s between the 0's to ensure that they are separated from each other.

Comment: Now I get it, thanks alot. But this approach is for me to understand easier right? If you were me, would you solve this in a shorter way?

Comment: Note that Sherlock's answer is the 8th Fibonacci number: $1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21$.

Comment: @f855a864 I can't really think of a shorter way, I'm afraid.